# Libgdx - Image class dispose

Tags: image, libgdx, textures, dispose

I am using LibGDX to create an Android game on Eclipse. I created an instance of Image class. I am not sure if I should dispose it. I created it like this;

`img = new Image(new Texture("img.png"));`

I created a Texture as well but I could not find a way to dispose it. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It's very error-prone to be storing your sole reference to a Disposable asset in part of your game's object graph. Use an AssetManager, or at least use one class that keeps track of all your textures and sounds, etc., (but seriously, use AssetManager--it has built-in reference counting). Then only that class has to handle disposing of all Disposables. Your actor can have a reference to a Texture, but it shouldn't hold the only reference, nor be responsible for disposing of the asset.

```
assetManager.load("img.png", Texture.class);
assetManager.finishLoading();

img = new Image(assetManager.get("img.png", Texture.class));

//...
assetManager.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like Texture implements disposeable so that would be the native object that needs to be disposed. You can read through [this documentation.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management)

You created an Image with an anonymous texture which just means you don't have a name you can reference it with so you can't dispose it. Your Texture asset needs to be referenced somewhere in your code so that you can dispose it at some appropriate time. Usually I would have a static Assets class which handles disposing all assets when needed (when stopping the app). Classes like Image use these assets but they don't have to worry about disposing them. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need `img` to be Actor so that I can add it to my stage. Which class can I use in order not to be worry about disposing the texture?

Comment: @Barodapride Better to use `AssetManager` as suggested by tenfour04. It handles loading and disposing, makes it easier to manage